# pagination without changing url or reload + add class to currant pagiantion number

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

On my index i have a picture as well as some text that i want to change (possibly with some animation) when i click on the next pagination number. I also want it to auto cahnge every X seconds. ive been looking into the pagination without reload or chaning url but i dont understand ajax (a website suggested ajax).

heres my html:

```
<!-- CHANE IMAGE -->
    <img src="image i want to use" class="image-content">
    <div class="image-info">

<!-- CHANGE TEXT -->
        <h1>add some headline here </h1>
        <div class="p">
            add some text here.<br/>
        </div>
    </div>

<div style="margin-top:-10px; position:absolute; width:45%; text-align:center;">
    <a href="#" class="page dark">First</a>
        <a href="#" class="page dark active-page">1</a>
        <a href="#" class="page dark">2</a>
        <a href="#" class="page dark">3</a>
        <a href="#" class="page dark">4</a>
        <a href="#" class="page dark">5</a>
    <a href="#" class="page dark">Last</a>
</div>
```

I use `class="active-page"` to change the color of the current page number so its clear what page you are on.

First and Last jumps to either page 1 or 5(in this case i only got 5 pages).

any suggestions to what i should be using?

(short question: how can i use ajax or other coding languages for pagination where i dont change url, reload page and change the class of current page?)